# Parse HTTP 1.0 header date/time stamp in java

Tags: java, apache, http, response, datestamp

I'm using Apache Client to send HTTP/1.0 request and receive the response in java.

Now I met the problem: the header of response contains the property, "Date" which could be those three formats:

- `Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT` // RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
- `Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT`  // RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
- `Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994` // ANSI C's asctime() format

My problem is that I can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse one type of those three formats but I can not find a good solution to parse ANY/ALL of those three formats.

(But HTTP/1.0 protocol requires to support all those formats, I can only support one of them)

Thanks indeed

Answer (score 2):

If you can't  put the time in milliseconds into the date field of the header of the server response (which is not conform to the http specification), then i think the only way is the following:

create three formats
 then parse the date value with every format and return or work with the value that didn't throw a parse exception.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateUtil](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/DateUtil.html) provided for the purpose.